# Twitter Bootstrap - width of navbar in row with other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In mobile version I need to have logo and navbar in one row, but then navbar content is too small (texts are on two rows, one row will be much better). Can I do something to increase width on 100%?

I create jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/8ayj7o36/

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="" class="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-9">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link dfa dfa dfdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link bbbb bbb bb</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You dont want the menu to be collapsible? and all the links inside one single row ?
or when the drop down opens, you want the links to be in one common row, than separate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `<a>` tag corresponding to your logo within the `navbar-header`, so that everything falls in single line. Now it is for you to adjust `col-group` according to your requirement. This is your modified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/235vdwfj/)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<a href="#" class="logo"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="" /></a>
-
-
-
</div>
```